# How we import the value in one xsl into another xsl in XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have below xsl created Address1.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="FCode"/>
      <xsl:param name="FName"/>
       <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:call-template name="Addtemplate"/>
       </xsl:template>
         <xsl:template name=" Addtemplate ">
  <xsl:variable name="TownType">
  <xsl:if test="$FCode!= ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="ABCValue"/>
          </xsl:if>
    </xsl:variable>
<Add>
     <addName>
      <xsl:value-of select="$TownName"/>
      </addName>
      <addType>
                 <xsl:value-of select="$TownType"/>
               </addType>
  </Add>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the second xsl Address2.xsl I want to import the value of **addName**.Tried below xsl but not getting the value.

Address2.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
<xsl:import href=" Address1.xsl "/>
<xsl:template match="/ ">
   
   <xsl:variable name="TempVar">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="Addtemplate">
         <xsl:value-of select=' addName'/>**<!--  I want addName value in the Address1.xsl to be mapped to TempVar variable  -->**
            
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want to extract the value of `<addName>` in from the contents of the variable `$TempVar` in Address2.xsl, you need the help of the `node-set()` function. Because this function is not standardized, various XSLT processors provide it in different ways. You need to say exactly which XSLT processor you're using.

Comment: Also it can't hurt to do a search for `node-set() function` and your paricular XSLT processor. It's guaranteed that this question has been answered before.

Comment: My XSLT processer don't support node-set() function.

Comment: Okay, and which XSLT processor is it, exactly?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 supporting processor.i am not sure about the processor name.

Comment: How do you execute your XSLT file? Via a command line tool? From a programming language?

Comment: Programming lanuage

Comment: I have modified my Address1.xsl....can you please review that.

Comment: You are **really** are making it impossible to help you. I've asked you three times now to give me the exact details about your XSLT processor and the best you've managed to come up with is "programming language". It couldn't hurt if you would start thinking along for a bit.

Comment: At the first you provided some code snippet,it seems to be good...can you please modify that for new input..that will be useful.